# POstgresSQL: ERROR: cannot delete from view "view_name"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to delete rows from a VIEW that appear in another VIEW. This is a trial operation with TABLE, but couldn't figure out how it works with VIEW.

For example, consider these two VIEWS:

```sql
SELECT * FROM trips;
 id      session_ids    distance
535780  {8024,8026}     74695.31
535268  {4567}            455.84
543477  {63331}         18546.94
540797  {43350}           412.65

SELECT * FROM sessions
session_id      timestamp
  4567     2016-04-07 15:39:31.578
  8024     2016-04-09 14:31:19.068
  1526     2016-04-04 07:50:24.544
 10311     2016-04-10 16:48:14.883
```

Note that the column `trips.session_ids` is type `integer array`, and the column `sessions.session_id` is type `integer`.

I want to delete rows from `trips` that are in `sessions`, so:

```sql
DELETE FROM trips t
USING sessions s
WHERE s.session_id = ANY(t.session_ids)
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  cannot delete from view "trips"
DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable deleting from the view, provide an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger or an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule.
SQL state: 55000
```

Expected result (after delete):

```sql
SELECT * FROM trips;
  id    session_ids  distance
543477  {63331}     18546.94
540797  {43350}       412.65
```

**EDIT**

To shed more light to my question, the `trips` VIEW was created from a large table (a subset of raw table), something like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW trips
AS
SELECT * FROM raw_table
WHERE some_condition;
```

Now I need a way to further filter `trips` to exclude rows that appear in `sessions`.

**EDIT-2**

As illustrated in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IAa5s8Zn),it worked fine, but not in my real database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE raw_table(id int, session_ids integer[], distance double precision);
INSERT INTO raw_table(id, session_ids, distance)
VALUES (535780,'{8024,8026}',4695.31),
(535268,'{4567}',455.84), 
(543477,'{63331}',18546.94),
(544400,'{15304}',25546.24),
(544210,'{12012,17577}',32546.24),
(540797,'{43350}',412.65);

CREATE VIEW trips 
AS
SELECT * FROM raw_table
WHERE distance < 25000;

CREATE TABLE sessions (session_id int, timestamp TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, timestamp)
VALUES (4567,'2016-04-07 15:39:31.578+01'),
(8024,'2016-04-09 14:31:19.068+01'),
(1526,'2016-04-04 07:50:24.544+01'),
(10311,'2016-04-10 16:48:14.883+01');

DELETE FROM trips t
USING sessions s
WHERE s.session_id = ANY(t.session_ids)
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: I do not understand the hint in the error message.

Comment: A simple WHERE condition (e.g. `where some_value > 100`) will not prevent deleting from the view. Please [edit] your table and show us the _complete_ code of your view (rather than showing us some dummy code [that doesn't have that problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/exa_3IYu))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I illustrated it in the linked fiddle.

Comment: Well, the fiddle shows that it's possible to delete from that view. So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Only very simple views allow data modifications.

If you want to run `DELETE` on a more complicated view, you have to write an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger that performs some appropriate action instead instead, for example delete something from the tables underlying the view.